# Implement token based auth using tastypie apikeyauthentication

Tags: django, tastypie

Is Tastypie APIKeyAuthentication similar to token based authentication systems?

It seems like API keys in tastypie are permanent until changed explicitly, whereas in token based auth the token is renewed after a specific period of time.

How can i use Tastypie to create a token based authentication system? Does tastypie has inbuilt capability to generating token based on time period.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any built in functionality into tastypie that lets you do it (which I assume will require some scheduled task), but I think you can use the following answer to limit the api key by time, and generate a new one if needed:

[Tastypie auto log out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17092212/tastypie-auto-log-out)

hope this helps.